# is it possible to loop over and select and remove items from an array randomly in swift?

Tags: swift

I am receiving an error:
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range

```
func buildShipYard(random: Int) {
    guard let opponentGold = camera.opponentResource.component(ofType: GoldComponent.self), let opponentTech = camera.opponentResource.component(ofType: TechLevelComponent.self)?.techLevel else { return }
    
    if opponentGold.gold >= prices.shipYardPrice {
        if opponentTech >= techRequirements.shipYardRequirement {
            opponentGold.spendGold(amount: prices.shipYardPrice)
            let selectedLocation = locations[random]
            selectedLocation.locationMenu.locationSelected = true
            let locationToBuildOn = locations.first(where: { $0.locationMenu.locationSelected })
            locationToBuildOn?.createShipYard(base: base)
            selectedLocation.locationMenu.locationSelected = false
            
            if let index = locations.firstIndex(where: { $0 == selectedLocation }) {
                locations.remove(at: index)
                print(locations.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the line `let selectedLocation = locations[random]` on the
second go around

Here is where I call the function:

```
for location in playerBase!.locations {
     if location.tavernBuilding {
          buildShipYard(random: mersenne.nextInt(upperBound: base.locations.count))
     } }
```

I am removing the specific index from the array each time so the following index should still be in bounds every time.

Comment: Why are you not using `random` as the index when removing?

Comment: There is no reason why I didn't use random as the index when removing, it would have been much simpler and more concise.

Comment: In the last loop you are using both `playerBase!.locations` and `base.locations`, although it isn't clear which array you are removing from it could very well be that you remove from one and get the count from the other. Make sure you have a "single source of truth", that is one and only one data source you work with in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You call `buildShipYard(random: mersenne.nextInt(upperBound: base.locations.count))` and while you haven't included the code for `nextInt` if it's randomly selecting a value from a closed range with an  upper bound of `locations.count` you might be forgetting that `count` is 1-indexed while an array is 0-indexed, and that you need to use `count-1`?

As a defensive measure you could check that `random` is a valid index at the start of the `buildShipYard` method, and then you can simply do:

```
locations.remove(at: index)
```

rather than the overly complicated and inefficient approach you currently have.

Comment: The mersenne.nextInt(upperBound:) returns a new random integer greater than or equal to zero and less than the value of the upperBound parameter. I see the answer though is that i put base.locations.count as the upperBound parameter when i am removing from the locations array(not the base.locations array).